# Cancelled my Booking.com reservation but hotel is still gonna charge me

Tags: cancellations, booking.com

So I booked two rooms in Booking.com and it said that there was free cancellation, so I was confident it reserving it, since I wasn't quite sure about booking the rooms but I wanted to reserve them anyways, so having free cancellation was really convenient. I reserved the rooms using an online debit card with barely any money, since I haven't got the money yet for the rooms.

The people I was supposed to stay with then bailed out so I cancelled the booking but it said it would charge me the cost of the two rooms. It clearly said free cancellation so Im confused as to why I'm going to be charged. I booked a new room that I would stay in instead.

My question is, why am I going to be charged for the cancellation and how will the hotel charge my empty online debit card?

Also, since I booked a new room, I'm planning to change my bank details on my new booking and put in a credit card. Would the hotel charge the new credit card for the old two rooms or still my empty debit card?

Also, is it still possible to retrieve my first reservation of two rooms and just sell it to others?

Comment: Do you have a PDF of your old booking confirmation that shows that you could cancel free of charge? Perhaps there was a deadline until which you had to cancel to get the free cancelation?

Comment: Did you contact Booking.com yet?

Comment: The hotel charged you for cancelling, and yet you are booking new rooms with them?

Comment: I have a screenshot of the booking that says Free Cancellation but I didnt get to take a screenshot of it saying that it had Free cancellation til the day before check in.

Comment: Yes I contacted Booking.com and they're taking long to respond. @MJeffryes

Comment: Without actual data showing the **eaxct** booking.com text saying 'free cancellation' this question is unanswerable. You may have misunderstood something. VTC as unclear.

Comment: Often, free cancellation is only available *until a certain date.* This date is mentioned on your confirmation. Maybe that date passed? I agree with the other person called Jan, this is unanswerable in its current state.